# MSMQ MessageQueue.BeginReceive(TimeSpan, Object)

Tags: c#, vb.net, msmq

I would like to pass a custom parameter to the ReceiveCompleted event handler via the ReceiveCompletedEventArgs object.  I don't want a timeout, but it seems as though there is no constructor (other than BeginReceive()) that doesn't expect a timeout value. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Please show your progress so far. Thank you

Comment: Note you can simplify your life by using TaskFactoty.FromAsync https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync?view=netframework-4.7.2 to adapt the old async API into the new Task-based async with first-class language support. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/await-operator

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just pass in MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout